# Why do I have to specify text format to render template with ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I'm using ActionMailer 3.0.7

According to the docs plain text emails are the default. So if I have an EnquiryNotifier mailer with a notify method then I expect that `app/views/enquiry_notifier/notify.text.plain.erb` will be rendered.

If I simply use `mail(someparams)` within the notify method then the body of the email is empty.

I read that ActionMailer is meant to scan the view directory to look for all types of templates.

However, if I specify the format within a block and do

```
mail(:to => 'somebody', :subject => 'something') do |format|
    format.text
end
```

then my template `notify.text.plain.erb` does get rendered.

Maybe unrelated: If I don't specify the format but rename the template to notify.erb then it works but the email is sent as text/html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what seems to work for me in rails 3.0.6:

1. I don't specify a format at all in my mailer class, I just let it find the view automatically.
2. I name my view "notify.text.erb"

Comment: And when I say "seems to work for me", I really mean "it does work for me". Just verified that my mail is sent with content-type "text/plain".